# How do I know who is sending me push notification and shut it down once and for all?

Tags: notifications

How do I know who is sending me this notification and shut it down once and for all?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These notifications seem to come from a website within Chrome, so you need to turn them off there.